# Why does this proof of reverse of string is correct?

Tags: formal-languages

> **Solution**
>
> Given that $a^R=a$, $$(wa)^R=aw^R\;.$$ Now we have to prove $(uv)^R=v^Ru^R$.
>
> Let us assume that $u=wb$ and $v=wa$.
>
> $$\begin{align*}
> LHS=(uv)^R=(wbwa)^R&=bw^R\cdot aw^R\;\color{red}\Leftarrow\\
> &=(bw^R)(aw^R)\\
> &=(bw)^R(aw)^R\\
> &=v^R\cdot u^R=RHS
> \end{align*}$$
>
> Hence proved

([Original screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uU6Sp.png))

It is a proof for reverse of string, $a\in\Sigma$ and $w\in\Sigma^*$

Isn't the part I marked with an arrow incorrect?

Isn't it supposed to be:  $aw^R\cdot bw^R$ ?

The key part that I don't understand:

\begin{align}LHS=(uv)^R=\color{red}{(wbwa)^R} &\,\color{red}{=bw^R\cdot aw^R}\\
&=(bw^R)(aw^R)\\
&=(bw)^R(aw)^R\\
&=v^R \cdot u^R=RHS
\end{align}

Comment: Please don't give screen shots like this. Use proper markup.

Comment: What is the context of the operator? What kind of group are we talking about?

Comment: Yes, it's an error. But it's balanced by another error in the last step so that it appears to get to the right place.

Comment: Yes I know the final answer is correct but this step drove me crazy. so the mistake is basically the third step? is there anything else wrong?

Comment: There are at least two errors. One that you pointed out where $(bw^R)\cdot(aw^R)$ should be $(aw^R)\cdot(bw^R)$, and a second one later where $bw$ is replaced by $v$ instead of by $u$, and vice versa for $aw$. The"solution" is a complete mess and would get a score of zero if it had been handed in by a student.

Comment: Also, welcome to math.stackexchange. You should feel free to post screen shots or anything else that is legible, and to ignore John Coleman's demands.

Comment: Thank you so much for your help MJD. I am happy to be part of the community.

Answer (score 1):

As written in the comments, the "solution" is messed up at several places.

1) What you noticed, in general we have $(wbwa)^R \ne bw^R \cdot aw^R$.

2) The assumption that $u$ and $v$ have a common prefix $w$ seems strange to me, in general we can just suppose that $u = wb$ and $v = w'a$ with $w,w' \in X^{\ast}, a,b \in X$.

3) The third and fourth line seem to be wrong, in general $(bw^R)(aw^R) \ne (bw)^R(aw)^R$.

4) In the last line he seems to replace $bw$ by $v$ and $aw$ by $u$, which is not consistent how $u$ and $v$ where choosen.

The exercise asks you to prove that the mapping $u \mapsto u^R$ is an anti-homomorphism, but strangely in the wrong solution at 1) and 2) he seems to use the wrong assumption that it is a homomorphism, which it is not, i.e. in general we have $(u\cdot v)^R \ne u^R \cdot v^R$.

To give a correct solution, let $u,v \in X^{\ast}$. We do induction on the length of $v$. If $|v| \in \{0,1\}$ the equation clearly holds, in the case $|v| = 1$ by the inductive definition of the reverse operation. Now suppose $|v| > 1$, then $uv = uwx$ with $x \in X$ and by definition we have
$$
 (uv)^R = (uwx)^R = x(uw)^R
$$
and by induction hypothesis applied to $|w| < |v|$ we have $(uw)^R = w^R u^R$, hence
$$
 (uv)^R = xw^R u^R.
$$ 
And again, by definition $xw^R = (wx)^R$, hence $(uv)^R = (wx)^R u^R = v^R\cdot u^R$. $\square$